# PyCharm hanging for a long time in iPython console with big data

Tags: pandas, pycharm, dataframe

I've seen some reports PyCharm is slow but I'm having an issue that seems that's too slow even compared to normal operation.

I have a big set of data in a pandas dataframe (read from a 440 MB csv file).

When I'm using the ipython console inside PyCharm, every time I try to handle that data, let's say, I write `my_data.` it just hangs there for about 30 seconds.

I don't really understand what is going on, but it seems PyCharm is going trough all the data to find some smart auto completion (which is a really dumb thing to do).

Any way to deactivate this behavior?

Comment: i have the same issue that you have. have you figured out the solution for this?

Comment: @uday Hi. No I haven't. I still face the same problem.

Comment: +1 on this issue.  So frustrating!  I have a ridiculous workaround.  I type `fram.whatever` then go back and add the 'e' to make `frame.whatever`.

Comment: I also suffer from this issue. any solution from PyCharm people?

Comment: same issue here +1 !!

Comment: This is only partly a PyCharm issue I'd say. Triggering autocompletion manually for a dataframe in a plain IPython console outside of PyCharm shows similar behavior for me. I don't understand why that should be so slow -- IPython issue?

Answer (score 7):

I have been facing the same issue for a long time as well: PyCharm debugging is extremely slow when using large pandas dataframes. If I want to view the contents of a dataframe in the Watches is often gives me a time out after waiting for minutes, so I basically stopped using the debug when working with dataframes

What I just found however, it that under

Files -> Settinggs -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Python Debugger

You have to switch on the "Gevent Compatible" flag

I also have switched on all the other flags in this window (Collect rum-time types information, attach subprocess, and PyQt compatible). But the Gevent compatible flag really does the job for me: it suddenly instantanuously gives me the dataframe contents in the debugger watches.

I am using PyCharm verion 2016.2.3

Comment: What does Gevent compatible flag do?

Answer (score 3):

Disabling "show variables" alleviated the slowness I was experiencing. To do this, go to

`Pycharm > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Console` and uncheck `Show console variables by default`.

Then restart your session.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not solved this issue yet:

I am using **pycharm 2020.2** on macos. I read in a not-too-large csv file as pandas.DataFrame format with 239150 rows x 95 columns.
When I typed `df.columns` in the interactive Debug console, similarly, the console hung for about 3 minutes to show the columns. We might have to wait for a real solution from pycharm update.

**For now, a quick dirty solution is:**

**1. To write `df.columns` in your .py file, and,**

**2. Select the command > right click > "Execute Selection in Python Console".**

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind disabling the autocompletion completely, I think this should work:

Go to `File > Settings (Ctrl+Alt+S) > IDE Settings > Editor > Code Completion`

And turn off `Insert selected variant by typing dot, space, etc.`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much you handle the data could hit memory limits.  Ipython remembers each In []: and Out []:.

`In` is a list that is appended to for each think you input.
`Out` is another list that gets appended to.

So if you have a very large array you are working with in `In` or `Out`  You will get several copies of the array.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?  How can the memory limits be adjusted?