# PyCharm's console hangs with "big" objects

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm, and typically run parts of my scripts in its Python console for debugging purposes. However, when I have to run something on a "big" variable (that consumes a lot of memory), the console becomes very slow.

Say `df` is a huge `pandas` data frame, as soon as I type `df.` in the console, it won't react anymore for 10-15 seconds. I can't tell whether this is pandas specific, since the only "big" variables I use come from pandas.

I'm running the community edition 3.4.1, pandas 0.14, Python 2.7.3, on Mac OS X 10.9.4 (with 8 GB of ram).

Size of `df`:

```
In[94]: df.values.nbytes + df.index.nbytes + df.columns.nbytes
Out[94]: 2229198184
```

Comment: Have you tried running it in another IDE, like Komodo or PyDev? Do they behave in a similar manner?

Comment: Also happens with PyCharm 2017, Python 3.6.2 and pandas 0.23

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem, and have yet to find a proper solution, but this is a workaround that I've been using, from [PyCharm hanging for a long time in iPython console with big data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868369/pycharm-hanging-for-a-long-time-in-ipython-console-with-big-data).

Instead of typing `df.columns` type `d.columns` and then go back and add the `f`. This at least prevents the hanging, although it renders the auto-completion a bit useless.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the "Variable Loading Policy" to "On Demand"?

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this problem since long. I always deactivate "Show Variables" option and run code. This increases speed everytime I do this.

Then Enable it again when you want to see variables.